# Finding the connected nodes to a specific node in osmnx graph

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I have created a graph using osmnx. and retrieved all the nodes that exist in that graph. now I want to find the connecting nodes to a specific node. I wonder if there is any method in osmnx or networkx to do so? or any other way. my code is as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx  as ox

#Defining top corners
top =  gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns = ['name', 'geometry'], crs = 4326, geometry = 'geometry')
top.at[0, 'geometry'] = Point(100.49209048590119,13.808722580927133)
top.at[0, 'name'] = 'tl'
top.at[1, 'geometry'] = Point(100.58494841499845, 13.809076204778961)
top.at[1, 'name'] = 'tr'


# Defining Bottom corners
bottom =  gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns = ['name', 'geometry'], crs = 4326, geometry = 'geometry')
bottom.at[0, 'geometry'] = Point(100.49141790672476,13.714053001208732)
bottom.at[0, 'name'] = 'bl'
bottom.at[1, 'geometry'] = Point(100.58476136747744, 13.717826488187361)
bottom.at[1, 'name'] = 'br'

#creating road network
combined = top.append(bottom)
convex = combined.unary_union.convex_hull
graph_extent = convex.buffer(0.02)
graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(graph_extent, network_type= "drive",custom_filter='["highway"!~"|secondary|residential|unclassified|tertiary"]')

#saving projection
graph_proj = ox.project_graph(graph)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph_proj, nodes=False)
CRS = edges.crs

nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph_proj, edges=False)
node_specific = [(100.4923576731243,13.70365525026876),(100.4721408793079,13.72276049159698)]
```

Comment: In networkx you can use `node_connected_component`. I never used osmnx so don't know if there is a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

Have simplified your code for generating a convex hull of points.

Connected nodes - not sure which you are defining

- nearest nodes in graph

  - have shown using **geopandas** `sjoin()`
  - have shown using **osmnx** `nearest_nodes()`
- shortest path between nearest nodes in graph

  - have shown using **osmnx** `shortest_path()`
- all of these I have visualised on a layered **folium** visualisation

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.geometry import Point, box, MultiPoint
import numpy as np
import folium

# creating road network
convex = MultiPoint(
    [
        Point(100.49209048590119, 13.808722580927133),
        Point(100.58494841499845, 13.809076204778961),
        Point(100.49141790672476, 13.714053001208732),
        Point(100.58476136747744, 13.717826488187361),
    ]
).convex_hull
graph_extent = convex.buffer(0.02)
graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(
    graph_extent,
    network_type="drive",
    custom_filter='["highway"!~"|secondary|residential|unclassified|tertiary"]',
)

# saving projection
graph_proj = ox.project_graph(graph)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph_proj, nodes=False)
CRS = edges.crs

nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph_proj, edges=False)
node_specific = [
    (100.4923576731243, 13.70365525026876),
    (100.4721408793079, 13.72276049159698),
]

# convert specific points to geodataframe and project to same CRS as projected graph
ns = np.array(node_specific)
gdf_node_specific = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(ns[:, 0], ns[:, 1]), crs="epsg:4386"
).to_crs(CRS)

# use geopandas to find nearest nodes in graph
gdf_connected = gdf_node_specific.sjoin_nearest(nodes)

# use osmnx to find nearest nodes in graph
orig, dest = ox.nearest_nodes(
    graph_proj, gdf_node_specific["geometry"].x, gdf_node_specific["geometry"].y
)

# visualise
m = nodes.explore(name="all nodes", height=300, width=500)
m = gdf_connected.explore(m=m, color="red", name="points")
# nodes on shortest path
nodes.loc[ox.shortest_path(graph_proj, orig, dest, weight="length")].explore(
    m=m, color="green", name="shortest path"
)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]